# Issue with login credentials Visual Studio LocalDB and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2014-localdb

I've built a code first project in Visual Studio.
When I run it the dbConext "HistoryContext" appears under the DataConnections tab in the Server Explorer in VS. But there is a little red x and when I try to click on HistoryContext I get the error message:

Cannot open database "History1" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'LAPTOP\Jerome'.

I went to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and connected to the localDb. I then went to security settings and both SQL and Windows authentication were ticked. But when I tried to just make it Windows authentication I got the error message:

TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

---

Alter failed for Server '(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=13.0.16100.1+((SSMS_Rel_16_5).161130-1812)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Alter+Server&LinkId=20476

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

RegCreateKeyEx() returned error 5, 'Access is denied.' (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 22002)
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=13.00.1601&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=22002&LinkId=20476

---

BUTTONS:
OK

---

Any advice about how to authenticate my credentials would be great.

Thanks,

Jerome

Comment: Is your db on sql server 2016?

Comment: Nope. Because i'm using "Code First" the database should be generated from the classes i've built but b/c of the authentication issue my database (called History1) never actually gets created. But i have other databases on the MSSQLLocalDb server and they are there on sql server 2016.